# Group By and Count in Access

Tags: ms-access, count, group-by

I have this table in access and I'm trying to do a Count and a Group by but am getting an error.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is group by the source the number of cars which have AC and are made before 2008.

I tried this:

```
SELECT SOURCE_ID, COUNT (SOURCE_ID) AS VEHICLES_WITH_AC
FROM VEHICLE
WHERE VEH_AC = 'Y'
GROUP BY  SOURCE_ID, VEH_AC,  VEH_YEAR
HAVING VEH_YEAR <'2008';
```

But im getting: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SOURCE_ID, COUNT (*) AS VEHICLES_WITH_AC
FROM VEHICLE
WHERE VEH_AC = 'Y' AND VEH_YEAR < '2008'
GROUP BY  SOURCE_ID;
```

1) You apparently require totals by source_id and nothing else, so you don't group by anything else.

2) your condition on VEH_YEAR should go in the where clause otherwise all veh_year rows will be selected and thrown away after aggregation.

Comment: yea this seems like the simplest answer instead of having to force a having clause in there. Thanks. On a side note, I was wondering how I could Order by VEHICLES_WITH_AC? I don't know what to call this temporary column so google a solution is giving me problems. 

For example I have a query which shows me employees with the least sum sales but I want the result to be descending.

Comment: @Batman. You can use the column ordinal numbers to sort on: ORDER BY 2 DESC will sort by the second column in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `;` after the `WHERE` clause. [reference](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/level-clause-t1155773.html)

Comment: Thanks, I caught that a bit earlier but that doesn't fix the problem however.

Comment: Perhaps replace the screenshot?

Comment: I added a new one showing what im trying and what im getting. Should the SOURCE_ID be distinct when i say group by source_id. However, its showing up twice (102)

Comment: Do the other fields -- `VEH_AC`,`VEH_YEAR` -- also have unique values?

Comment: The only unique value in the table is model_id and vehicle id. AC and YEAR are not unique its just Y or N for each entity instance.

Comment: I think the issue is that im using the having clause incorrectly for what I want to achieve. I could easily use an AND statement with WHERE and Group by SourceID only. My issue is that im working on an assignment that requires me to write queries with a having clause.

Comment: I don't think that should affect the results -- once you're grouping by the `VEH_YEAR`, the `HAVING` clause should refer to the grouped value, not the original value. What happens when you put the `VEH_YEAR < '2008'` criteria together with the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: If i have it with the where statemet and have group by source and nothing else. It works. It counts all the cars with AC before 2008 and the result is source 101 = 3 cars 102 = 2cars 103 = 5 cars for example.